# Filter inherited model field odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am creating a custom module in which i have a many2one field that has the entries from res.partner with supplier= True. My field,

```
seller = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Select Seller")
```

Read that i can do this in my xml file and tried,

```
 <data>

          <record id="test_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Tests</field>
            <field name="res_model">tests.alltests</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[('supplier','=',True)]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Test
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>





        <menuitem id="quality_main_menu"
                name="Quality"/>
        <menuitem id="test_create" parent="quality_main_menu" name="Test" action="test_menu_action"/>

    </data>
```

which gave me the following error,

```
Odoo Server Error ........
ValueError: Invalid field 'supplier' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('supplier', '=', True) on tests_alltests (ctx: )
```

How do i do it correctly?

I am using odoo V12 community edition.

Comment: Instead of `('supplier', '=', True)`, you can try `('supplier', '!=', False)`

Comment: @travisw now im getting the same error with '!=' instead of '='.

Comment: Your field is defined as `seller`, but your domain uses `supplier`. Is that correct? What class is `seller` a part of?

Comment: @travisw Yes, i was trying to get the entries with supplier=true from res.partner. seller is part of alltests class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need to do that in the action, 
instead you should do this in the field it self:

1. If the domain must be always applied best thing you do is 
   put it in the field declaration so when ever you use it in any
   view the domain is automatically applied.

```py
     seller = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 
                        string="Select Seller",
                        domain="[('supplier','=',True)]")
```

2. If the domain is not always applied then add it the XML view when ever you need it

```xml
    <field name="seller" domain="[('supplier','=',True)]"/>
```

And for the domain that you used in the action is for another situation
for example if you want to create a menu for `res.partner` and you want 
the users to see only supplier, you can add the domain to action this way
no matter what the user do with the search view this domain is always added
to the chosen filter.

Comment: Think i should be using the first method. Im new to odoo. Thanks for correcting.